# QML Scene2D -> QThread causes seg fault

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qthread

Trying to use the Qt 5.9 QML Scene2D functionality to render a simple LineChart widget onto a 3D object inside the gui of my app, when I exit (responding to a keypress, but any other means causes the same issue) the output issues the following message:

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

Causing a segfault, and 50% of the time the execution of the application hangs, requiring a forced closure.

Running the [QML Scene2D example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-scene2d-example.html) from Qt causes the same QThread fault, although as it is running as an Entity in the main window, the application seems to exit "correctly". It would seem that the Scene2D offline texture rendering creates threads that are not properly terminated whene the program is closed.

Looking through the documentation and examples I can't seem to find a way to correctly and orderly do this shutdown, I would appreciate any pointers in this direction.

Comment: Which Qt version you use?

Comment: edited question, Qt 5.9

Comment: Ok, and which minor version? The minor versions contain dozens or sometimes hundreds of bug fixes. You should be using 5.9.7.